# What is this total length

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, geometry, analysis, graph-theory

What is the value of the total length of all the edges connecting the vertices of a regular $k$-gon that is inscribed
on a unit circle?

Comment: Thanks a lot for any helpful answers.

Comment: Do you mean the edges of the polygon, or is there an edge between every pair of vertices?

Comment: Are you comfortable with complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

(This tells you exactly what to do, and I left some minor computation for you.)

First, we assume that $k$ is odd, and $k = 2n + 1$. For any integer $ 1 \leq i \leq n$, there are $k$ pairs of vertices that are length $i$ apart. Since the central angle is $\frac{2i\pi}{n}$, their distance is $2 \sin \frac{i\pi}{n}$. Hence, the sum of distances is

$$k \sum_{i=1}^n 2 \sin \frac{i\pi}{n}, $$

which you should recognize as a telescoping trigonometric sum, and can simplify to a closed form.

The case $k=2n$ is even is dealt similarly, just that there are only $n$ pairs of vertices that are $n$ vertices apart.